# MvvmCross Failed to Resolve Type

Tags: ios, xamarin, mvvmcross

I'm using MvvmCross v6.2.1 in an iOS project and am getting the following exception:
*MvvmCross.Exceptions.MvxIoCResolveException has been thrown. Failed to resolve type Countr.Core.Services.IMediaManagerService.*
In an attempt to solve this I added some debugging code to App.cs

```
using MvvmCross.IoC;
using Countr.Core.ViewModels;
using Countr.Core.Services;
using MvvmCross;
using MvvmCross.ViewModels;
using System.Linq;

namespace Countr.Core
{
    public class App : MvxApplication
    {
        public override void Initialize()
        {
            CreatableTypes()
                .EndingWith("Service")
                .AsInterfaces()
                .RegisterAsLazySingleton();

            CreatableTypes()
                .EndingWith("Repository")
                .AsInterfaces()
                .RegisterAsLazySingleton();

         var x = new MediaManagerService();
         var y = this.CreatableTypes().FirstOrDefault(t => t.Name == "MediaManagerService");
         var z = Mvx.IoCProvider.Resolve<IMediaManagerService>();

            RegisterAppStart<ArticlesViewModel>();
        }
    }
}
```

The variables x and y are successfully created, i.e., there is no error creating the MediaManagerService and the MediaManagerService is listed in the CreatableTypes() collection. However the code blows up when initializing the variable z,  i.e., when executing the Resolve method.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did it works fine in old version?

Comment: Does `Mvx.IoCProvider.GetSingleton<IMediaManagerService>()` throws the same error? does the exception have an InnerException or it's just that?

Comment: Lucas, this is new code. No old version to test.

Comment: fmaccaroni. GetSingleton() throws the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if you have more than one `MediaManagerService` because it could be trying to construct another instance.

Instead of

`var y = this.CreatableTypes().FirstOrDefault(t => t.Name == "MediaManagerService");`

check

`var ylist = this.CreatableTypes().Where(t => t.Name == "MediaManagerService").ToList();`

If you still have just one occurrence of `MediaManagerService` try registering like

`Mvx.IoCProvider.LazyConstructAndRegisterSingleton<IMediaManagerService, MediaManagerService>();`

If you have more than one occurrence of the implementation then you can do the aforementioned solution for one occurrence after the registering of the `CreatableTypes` so that it overrides the previous registration or you can simple change the name of the interface/implementation so that the scan gives you a unique pair of Interface/Implementation to register.

Comment: Found the problem when I tried to use the LazyConstructAndRegisterSingleton and the source code was flagged with an error. The interface definition IMediaManagerService and the actual MediaManagerService class were out of sync. I wasn't actually referencing the interface when I created the class and the interface declared a property as read/write and in the class it was defined as read only. Once I referenced the interface in the class declaration the error was highlighted immediately.